# Apps installed on external SD card and web shortcuts dissapeared from home screen after reboot

Tags: android

I have set the phone to install the apps on the external SD card. After a reboot all the icons of the apps installed on the external SD card dissapeared from home screen. Also, all the web shortcuts dissapeared and it is not possible to add them again (I guess the launcher checks to see if the shortcut already exists).

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your programming question?

Comment: I forgot about this little detail. I wanted to post it in superuser. I just added it in superuser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go in Settings, Apps, All.
2. Look for the app named Launcher*.
3. Tap on it and then tap on Force stop.